# How do I pass a Ruby local variable from a method to a sub-method?

Tags: ruby, variables

Given this simple Ruby code:

```
def testMethod
  testVar = 1
  def subTestMethod
    if testVar == 1
      puts 'Yes'
    else
      puts 'No'
    end
  end
  subTestMethod
end

testMethod
```

Is there any way to pass the local `testVar` variable to the sub-method without being forced to use a class variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you have, very likely does not do what you want:

The inner `def` in your code does *not* define a local method. Instead it defines `subTextMethod` as a global method in the `Object` class as soon as `testMethod` is called for the first time. That means that after you call testMethod, you'll be able to call `subTestMethod` from anywhere.

The fact that `subTestMethod` is not local to `testMethod` of course also means that `subTestMethod` can't close over `testMethod`'s local variables.

To get the behaviour you want, you might want to use a lambda like this (or rethink your design so that you don't need any nested functions):

```
def testMethod
  testVar = 1
  subTestLambda = lambda do
    if testVar == 1
      puts 'Yes'
    else
      puts 'No'
    end
  end
  subTestLambda.call
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby, only blocks (and lambda literals) can be closures. So, you'll have to use a block to define the method:

```
def testMethod
  testVar = 1
  Object.send(:define_method, :subTestMethod) do
    if testVar == 1
      puts 'Yes'
    else
      puts 'No'
    end
  end
  subTestMethod
end

testMethod
```

As others have already pointed out, whether or not this does what you think it does depends of course on exactly *what* you think it does, but most likely, it *doesn't*.

Just a couple of style tips: methods and (non-constant) variables follow a `snake_case` naming convention, you use empty lines to separate initialization from the actual work and the return value, and everything is an expression.

So, your `testMethod`, `subTestMethod` and `testVar` should rather be named `test_method`, `sub_test_method` and `test_var`. There should be an empty line before `define_method` and before `sub_test_method`. And you can pull the `puts` outside of the `if` expression, since, well it *is* an *expression* and thus returns its value:

```
def test_method
  test_var = 1

  Object.send(:define_method, :sub_test_method) do
    puts(if test_var == 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
  end

  sub_test_method
end

test_method
```

What you probably rather want is a lambda:

```
def test_method
  test_var = 1

  sub_test_lambda = -> { puts(if test_var == 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) }

  sub_test_lambda.()
end

test_method
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `testVar` as a parameter to `subTestMethod`

```
def testMethod
  testVar = 1
  def subTestMethod(testVar)
    if testVar == 1
      puts 'Yes'
    else
      puts 'No'
    end
  end
  subTestMethod testVar
end
```

Comment: Note that this will very likely not have the behaviour Michael desires as it will still define `subTestMethod` as a "global" method and not as a local function like it would for example in python.

Comment: Yes `def` will define a new method `subTestMethod` which can be invoked like `testMethod`.